# Error while building Hadoop 0.20 source code using Ant

Tags: java, hadoop, ant

I am compiling **hadoop 0.20.0** source code to create its binary distribution(hadoop-0.20.0.tar.gz). **Ant** is used to compile and package this source code.I installed ANT, Apache forrest and libtool.

- After this i applied command "***ant compile***" --Compiled
  succesfully
- when i applied command ***ant package -Djava5.home=$JAVA_HOME -Dforrest.home=$FORREST_HOME***. 
  I am getting following error.(Both JAVA_HOME and FORREST_HOME is set properly):
  [image: Build Failed]

Please help me out:

Comment: What is the result of running `ant -version`?

Comment: This is the result--  **Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you encountered a bug that existed only in Ant 1.9.3:

[Bugzilla Report 55949: NPE in javadoc when using a custom doclet](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55949)

You have several options:

- Upgrade to a newer version of Ant, such as Ant 1.9.4.
- Downgrade to an older version of Ant, such as Ant 1.9.2.
- Edit the `build.xml` file in the hadoop 0.20.0 source code.

If you go with the "Edit the `build.xml`" option, open the file in a text editor and change line 981 from...

```
<javadoc>
```

...to...

```
<javadoc postProcessGeneratedJavadocs="false">
```